# Probability of winning chocolates in throwing game

Tags: probability

In urn there are 12 balls from which 7 are green.John draws at random 4 balls.Then he hits a target with the green balls he drew(if there are any).His probability of hitting successfully is $\frac{1}{4}$ in every shot and if he succeeds he wins a chocolate for every successful hit.

a)What is the probability John to win exactly 2 chocolates?

b)if a) happened,what is the probability he drew exactly 3 green balls from the urn?

How I solved it I think : Let $A$ be the event John wins 2 chocolates, and let $H_{i}$ for $i$ in ${[0,1,2,3,4]}$ be the event - John drew exactly $i$ green balls.

So for a) we seek $P(A|H_{1} \cup H_{2} \cup H_{3} \cup H_{4}) =P(A|H_{0})P(H_{0})+(A|H_{1})P(H_{1})+P(A|H_{2})P(H_{2})+P(A|H_{3})P(H_{3})+P(A|H_{4})P(H_{4})$.

The cases where $i=0$ and $i=1$ , the probability  is $0$ so we need to find 
$P(A|H_{2})P(H_{2})+P(A|H_{3})P(H_{3})+P(A|H_{4})P(H_{4})$.

$P(H_{2}) = \frac{ \binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{12}{4}}$ ,
$P(H_{3}) = \frac{ \binom{7}{3}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{12}{4}}$ ,$P(H_{4}) = \frac{ \binom{7}{4}\binom{5}{0}}{\binom{12}{4}}$ ,

$P(A|H_{2})=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}$ - since we want him to succeed two times

$P(A|H_{3})=3(\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4})$  - since we want two success and 1 failure multiplied by 3 for the permutations

$P(A|H_{4})=6(\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4})$

Now we just plug them in above and find the answer
for b) I think we seek  $P(H_{3}|A)=?$ which can be found applying Bayes's theorem and plugging in the values from a)

Is my solution correct?

Comment: "b) if a) happened what is the probability **before that** that he drew exactly 3 green balls". Do you mean "if he wins exactly 2 chocolates, what is the probability that he drew exactly 3 green balls". The "before that" is really confusing. You are presumably asking how we update the prior to the posterior distribution. But "the probability before that" appears to refer to the prior distribution.

Comment: yes true, i have deleted "before that"

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that John can only win 2 chocolates if he drew at least 2 green balls from the urn. So the first step is to find the probs of drawing 2, 3 and 4 greens from the urn.

We have $$p(2G)= 6\frac{7}{12}\frac{6}{11}\frac{5}{10}\frac{4}{9}=\frac{42}{99}$$ Similarly $$p(3G)=\frac{35}{99},p(4G)=\frac{7}{99}$$

We also need to work out $$p(2c|2G)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{8}{128},\quad p(2c|3G)=3\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}=\frac{18}{128},\quad p(2c|4G)=6\frac{9}{256}=\frac{3}{128}$$

So now we can apply Bayes to get that $$p(3G|2c)=\frac{p(2c|3G)p(3G)}{p(2c|2G)p(2G)+p(2c|3G)p(3G)+p(2c|4G)p(4G)}$$ $$=\frac{18\cdot35}{8\cdot42+18\cdot35+3\cdot7}=\frac{630}{987}\approx0.64$$